# 401 error when im going to do a get request in postman

Tags: java, postman

> Similar to 403 Forbidden, but specifically for use when authentication
> is possible but has failed or not yet been provided. The response must
> include a WWW-Authenticate header field containing a challenge
> applicable to the requested resource.

```java
@RestController()
@RequestMapping("/rest")
public class PaisRestController {

    IPaisService paisService;

    @GetMapping("/example")
    public String home(@RequestAttribute("Username") String username) {
        return "Hello, " + username + "!";
    }

    @GetMapping("/findById/{pais_id}")
    public Pais getPaisById(@PathVariable("pais_id") Long pais_id) {
        System.out.println(paisService.getPaisPorId(pais_id));
        return paisService.getPaisPorId(pais_id);

    }

}           
}
```

I don't know how to fix this problem, when I send the request in postman, I get this error. I have my Bearer Token in my headers values and authorizations in keys.
The URL I'm using:

> http://localhost:8080/CashLetterAPI/rest/findById/1

[Project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DAqfc.png)

UPDATE 2:

My configure method:

```
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http
                .antMatcher("/rest/**")
                .authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest().permitAll()
            .and()
                .addFilterBefore(customJWTAuthFilter, BasicAuthenticationFilter.class)
                .exceptionHandling()
                .authenticationEntryPoint(unauthorizedRestEntryPoint)
            .and()
                .csrf().disable();
        }
    }
```

Comment: We'll need to see more of your code (can you show the _entire_ class, at least, and make it clear where the type `Pais` is defined and where `paisService` comes from?) to be able to help with this.

Comment: IPaisService is the interface of PaisServiceImpl

Comment: Added too the configure method..maybe that's the problem..